# 301 Redirect HTTP to HTTPS: Best Way

Tags: html, wordpress, https

I have been searching for the perfect 301 redirect. But I am finding so many solutions and do not know which one is the best. Though the top 2 option I have tried and they are working.

This is for a **completely new site** where I want to redirect everything from **http://www.exampledomain.com** to **https://www.exampledomain.com**

Would be great if someone help me out on this one.

I am finding many references, as follows:

1.
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.exampledomain.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>`

2.
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

3.
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>`

4.
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

5.
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

6.
`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]`

Thanks a ton,
Jay

Comment: Those rules don't all do the same thing, some will also work for subdomains, others won't. Some will rely on the Port, others on the HTTPS environment variable. Some will redirect to different targets depending on the URL. And none of them will do what you want if you're behind a reverse proxy that handles the SSL and talks plain HTTP to the backend where your rules are (like CloudFlare might, if you don't set it up to do the redirects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all are pretty the same, only with small variantions.

1. detects non-https traffic by port number (80), not by variable %{HTTPS}, and redirects only to https://www.exampledomain.com/. So skip this one.
2. This is the "core" version, it says "when the request is http-only, redirect it to adequate https version". Nothing more, nothing less.
3. Similar to 2, but also adds condition whether mod_rewrite is available in Apache. You don't need to add it if you are sure (without mod_rewrite, none of these methods will work anyway). And also, it strips "www" on beginning of domain name, so all traffic is redirected to non-www version of the website (from www.somedomain.com to somedomain.com)
4. This one is missing [L,R=301], it was probably omitted by mistake
5. Similar to 2, but redirects to www version of domain name.
6. Similar to 2, but it is not generic, works only for example.com (which you don't want to use in real world).

So, pick 2 if you don't want to fiddle with www in address, or pick 3 or 5 if you do. You can add `RewriteEngine On` on beginning of .htaccess, it is needed onlu once, not for every rule. And you can add the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule>` from 3. if you want to use the same code on different servers and you are not sure which modules will be available.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.Should it be like below? By default from Begin WordPress to End WordPress is there. I have added the redirection code above that.

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`